# Regex that matches text *not* between brackets

Tags: php, sql, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will match all the bold text below in a PHP (PCRE) compatible pattern, this is just an example query that it needs to match, so it can't be so specific that it won't work on other similar queries.

> select  **a.*, (select count(*) from table1 ) as t1, (select
>   count(*) from table2 ) as t2, (select count(*) from table3 ) as t3,
>   col1, col2** from table4 as a LEFT JOIN ( SELECT g2.*,g1.id from
>   table5 ) as g ON ( a.id = g.id ) );

*UPDATE: My idea was to match the word FROM that is not between any brackets and everything before it. The end goal is to replace all the bold text with "COUNT(*)" for a database abstraction layer.

Comment: Not sure this is possible with regex, since you have nested queries.

Comment: That's going to be tough given the nested nature of your `SELECT`.

Comment: To do this, we'd need to know what's special or unique about the bold part as opposed to the non-bold, especially at the point where they meet - otherwise your stipulation about being "so specific" makes this impossible. For example, should it be only the first three tables included, or up to the first table that specifies columns...?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? The example you give doesn't match the title of your question. Which one is it: the text in bold, or text not between brackets (and what does that mean exactly)?

Comment: @Miky - edits had removed the bold from the text

Comment: I was thinking the best way to approach it is to match the word FROM and everything before it that is not between any brackets.

Comment: @MarkBaker and George - which brackets are you talking about? I can see the text in bold but I don't see any brackets. And if it is parentheses that you're referring to - then why are the inner queries in bold too? The question is very confusing and as others have pointed out, not a good candidate for RegEx..

Comment: In other words, you need the column list of the main query? Does that sound right? (Also, the word you want is "parentheses", not "brackets".)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "How can I use regexes to find the expressions that are selected at the *top level* of a SQL query," the short answer is, you can't.

SQL is *not* a "regular language" (any language that allows nesting of parentheses is not), so you're blocked right there.  I believe it is a context-sensitive grammar, so you would need a separate lexical analyzer and parser.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this problem.

Simply iterate over all characters and keep track of your nesting level. When you detect a left parenthesis, increment your nesting level by 1. When you detect a right parenthesis, decrement your nesting level by 1. Whenever you find the word "from", mark the position if your nesting level is 0 (and return the substring from the beginning up to that position), otherwise ignore it and keep going.

This will be fragile in the case of an invalid query, but it should work if the query is known to be valid.